# Cake PHP event chaining with Js Helper

Tags: cakephp, helper, method-chaining

Hello you coders out there,
I want to do an event chaining with the Js helper but can´t figure out how to do that with the cookbook.

Scenario:
I have an input field, which is fired onkeyup with ajax. That works fine.

The goal:
The ajax call should be fired after putting 3 digits into the field, not everytime.

My thoughts:
Maybe the chaining of the helper could get me out. I thought the return true would tell the helper to go on, otherwise do nothing. But I didn´t find any info. My code so far:

```
<?php $check = " 
    if($(this).val().length >3){
        return true;
    };"; ?>
<?php echo $this->Js->get('#ajaxSearchSCourier')->event('keyup', $check)->request(
    array('controller'=>'Posts', 'action'=>'index'),
        array(
            'update' => '#erfolgreich_ajax',
            'before' => $before,
            'success' => $success,
            'async' => true,
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'data'=>$this->Js->serializeForm(array('isForm'=>'false', 'inline'=>'true'))
        )
    );
?>
```

I hope you have an idea. Many thanks in advance,
Karl

Comment: Personally, I try to avoid writing to much javascript via the JsHelper. Many times writing the javascript yourself is easier to follow and debug. First of all, be carefull when using double quotes (") here, as PHP might see the `$` in `$(this)` as a variable. It might be best to add the *generated* JavaScript to your question as well, so people here can assist better in finding the answer

Answer (score 0):

Forget the JsHelper and write js code yourself. Check my related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225788/cakephp-jshelper-add-remove-class/12225949#12225949).