# Use .on() instead of .bind() in CakePhp JsHelper

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I use the JsHelper of CakePHP to generete some of the Ajax in my code. When I use

```
$this->Js->get('#searchCity')->event(
        'click', $this->Js->request(
                'http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON', array(
            'async' => true,
            'dataExpression' => true,
            'method' => 'GET',
            'data' => "{}",
            'dataType' => 'JSON',
            'success' => ""
                )
        )
);
```

the helper output is something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#searchCity").bind("click", function(event) {
        $.ajax({async: true, data: {},
            dataType: "JSON", success: function(data, textStatus) {
            }, type: "GET", url: "http:\/\/api.geonames.org\/searchJSON"});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Apparently, some versions of Internet Explorer have problems dealing with the .bind() function, so this code doesn't work on IE.

I read that the `.on()` function is a good replacement.

The question is: Can I replace `.bind()` for `.on()` without touching the CakePHP core? Or is there any other clever solution?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I suggest you not to use these js helpers, they usually suck :(

Comment: on() and bind() will work exactly the same. Just that using on(), you could delegate event but then need to change syntax. I guess your issue (what issue???) is not relative to bind(). Any reference regarding IE getting issue with bind()?

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.8.3. I'm realizing that they suck now, but unfortunately there is a lot of code already written with this helper...

Comment: Can you provide more info about IE? Is it triggering any errors? What's the symptom?

Comment: Can't you extend this library function event() to run with ON instead of BIND?

Comment: I'm testing on IE 9, and it doesn't display any error. This code should execute when I click the #searchCity button. Works perfectly on Chrome, Firefox and Opera, but on IE, the button is not triggering any action

Comment: Forget the JsHelper and directly write jquery code. More info [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225949/1230763

Comment: I think I discovered what is going on. Since I'm trying to get data from a external url, IE is blocking the request because of the same origin policy. Apparently, I can't request a external url in my page. How to workaround this?